# Get error file not found in production build Next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, next.js

when I try to run the production build it shows me the error shown in the attached screenshot. It shows a file not found but file exists at that particular path.Don't know why this is happen

[image]

Comment: The paths the app is trying to load don't seem right. How are you building and running the production build?